# How do I split a string into separate variables by the second colon?

Tags: r, text, split

I have a string:

```
 [1] "x: user1 : value1"
 [2] ": user2 : value2"
 [3] ": user2 value3"
 [4] ": user4 : value4"
```

I need to split user id's by the second colon into a **user_id** variable, and the text after the second colon into a **var1** variable. 
I also need to add a **class** variable to each observation, that will be populated with **a** if there were two colons. If there is no second colon in the string, then I need the **class** variable to be populated with **b**.

The dataframe I need at the end looks like this:

```
user_id    var1       class
  user1    value1       a
  user2    value2       a
  user2    value3       b
  user4    value4       a
```

Is there a convenient way in R to do this using `substr`?

Answer (score 1):

We can create a `data.frame` from the `vector` of strings by extracting only the needed substring with `sub` and using `read.csv`.  We match 0 or more characters that are not a `:` (`[^:]*`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by a `:` followed by one or more white space character (`\\s+`), followed by word (`\\w+`), captured as a group (`(...)`), followed by matching the punctuation characters or white space and the second word.  In the replacement, we use the backreference for the captured groups separated by a `,`.  It is used as input to `read.csv` to read it as 2 column `data.frame`.  The 'class' column is created using the `str_count` from `stringr` package

```
library(stringr)
df1 <- read.csv(text=sub("^[^:]*:\\s+(\\w+)[[:punct:] ]+(\\w+)", "\\1,\\2", str1), 
    header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, col.names = c("user_id", "var1"))
df1$class <-  c("b", "a")[str_count(str1, ":")]
df1
#  user_id   var1 class
#1   user1 value1     a
#2   user2 value2     a
#3   user2 value3     b
#4   user4 value4     a
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c( "x: user1 : value1", ": user2 : value2", ": user2 value3", ": user4 : value4")
```